# How to configure ports used for communication between R and RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

First, I'm not a R/RStudio user at all. I'm a Windows admin with the task to configure R and RStudio on a multi-user Citrix environment. To identify users between the multiple sessions, we are using the Palo Alto Terminal Server agent which will allocate a range of ports for each user and use them to identify each users. That's then used to give limited and specific access to resources for each users.

The problem is that the TS Agent also intercept the localhost connection that's created when you start RStudio (process rsession) and RStudio then cannot connect to R. One possible solution to solve this problem is to have control on the ports used when this local session is started.

I have made multiple research on the Internet but I have been unable to find if/how you can change the ports that are used. I have found different config files but none that seem to allow me to fix a single port or a port range.

Any insights on the way to fix the ports for the rsession process so I can better control them? Or another way to look at the problem: do you know the port range used by R/RStudio when they communicate together through the rsession? I can simply avoid using these range with the TS Agent.

Comment: May be worth asking at the Rstudio community forum. https://community.rstudio.com/

Comment: Thanks. I will ask the question there as well. :)

Comment: Hmm, doing IPC via randomly allocated ports is *fairly common*. Are you saying that none of the applications using this work on your compute environment?

Comment: @KonradRudolph : yep. With the default settings, any apps using IPC will have its communication trapped by the TS Agent. There are other settings that allow you to trap only ports that are within the defined ranged that could work in my case but I need to fix the port used by R/RStudio and do some extended testing to be sure that it has no impact on other apps.
In the meantime, I will open a support case with the vendor to ask if there's a solution to ignore IPC connection (Maybe a version of the tool in development allow this)

Answer (score 0):

I have only skimmed through the RStudio Source code, but it seems that the port is assigned randomly:
https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/bcc8655ba3676e3155d80296c421362881340a0f/src/node/desktop/src/main/application.ts#L226

However, it also seems like there is a startup parameter `--www-port` to set the port:
https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/bcc8655ba3676e3155d80296c421362881340a0f/src/node/desktop/src/main/session-launcher.ts#L592

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this parameter does not seem to work in my case. 
I have contacted Palo Alto to ask them if there's a way to set up the TS Agent to ignore localhost communication / IPC as it will be a cleaner solution.